# Firebase query results are being logged but are not being displayed in the HTML

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase and Angular, I am able to log results of a query, however I cannot display the results in my HTML.

The HTML:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-label class="signinlabel">Chat</ion-label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="What is your message?" (keyup.enter)="Send($event.target.value)">
  <div>
    <p *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.message}}</p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The TS for the Query:

```
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=> {
      this.user = user;
      console.log('authState',user);
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        var uid = user.uid;
        // ...
        firebase.database().ref('/userprofile/' + uid + '/' + 'list').once('value').then((snapshot)=> {
          var listkey = (snapshot.val());
          console.log("ionViewDidLoad listkey",listkey)
          this.listKey = listkey;
          this.getChat(listkey)
                    .subscribe(items => {console.log("chat messages", items); this.item = items});
        });
      }
      else {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(SignInPage);
        // User is signed out.
      }
    });
  }

  getChat(listkey): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    console.log('CHAT.db.list','userlists/' + listkey + '/chat');
    return this.af.list('userlists/' + listkey + '/chat', {
      query: {
        limitToLast: 50,
      }
    });
  }
```

My DB structure is:

```
{
  "-L0MCOODnFTshrVCJiZN" : {
    "chat" : {
      "-L1z-K-0JC2GMxx4rwmz" : {
        "message" : "test1"
      },
      "-L1z-KkxxPAVr-_ptDJ6" : {
        "message" : "test2"
      },
      "-L1z-LILho3sszvU0zfR" : {
        "message" : "test3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am correctly logging `chat messages` and `CHAT.db.list`, but I still can't output the messages to `{{item.message}}`. Why can't I get this to work?

Comment: Should it be `this.items = items`, instead of `this.item = items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using items in template and assigning to item inside the component , change it as **`items`**

```
.subscribe(items => {console.log("chat messages", items); this.items = items});
```